# How to create a folder inside a folder

Tags: android

So I created a folder in the internal storage like this:

```
File folder1 = getBaseContext().getDir("DataBase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
```

Now how to I create a new folder inside that folder1?

I tried this (below), but this creates a file and not a folder. . .

```
File insideFolder = new File (folder1,"Important Database");
```

I also tried calling mkdir but it seems like insideFolder is still a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now how to I create a new folder inside that folder1?

`new File(folder1, "subdirname").mkdir();`

> Now how to I create a new folder inside that folder1?

If the file was already there due to some previous experiment of yours, `mkdir()` will not delete it. You will need to delete it yourself.

Comment: can you make that so you can set that value to a file? I mean you can't do File insideFolder = new File(folder1, "subdirname").mkdir(). I tried File insideFolder = new File (folder1, "subdirname"); and then insideFolder.mkdir() and this seems to create a file, instead of a folder. I reinstalled my application so that there isn't a duplicate. . .

Comment: @coolcool1994: "and then insideFolder.mkdir() and this seems to create a file, instead of a folder" -- that code will create a directory.

Comment: You need to call mkdir afterwards to make that a file. . .