# How to make a folder in a folder: Android

Tags: android

```
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
         {

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Raw Image");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 
            Date d = new Date();
            CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
            File output = new File(imagesFolder, s.toString() + ".jpg");

            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            OutputStream imageFileOS;

            try {
                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();



    };
```

Currently i am creating a folder name "Raw Image" to save the image. What if i want to create more folders in the "Raw Image folder"? Any suggestions please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538733/how-to-create-a-folder-inside-a-folder..see this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way you will create a folder named "another_folder" in the "Raw Image" folder:

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Raw Image/another_folder");
```

Also you should avoid creating folder/file with blank space in their names

Answer (score 1):

you have to check whether the folder is already exist or not. you have to add only one line of code

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Punch");

if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
}
else { //do nothing
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try following code

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Raw Image");
File folder= new File(imagesFolder , "yourfolder name");
        folder.mkdirs();
```